# How do I save the output I have to a new text file?

Tags: python

So basically, I have a super long output, and I want to be able to save this output to a brand new text file, without changing my old file. This is my code thus far, I basically just need to know what to do with my out_file variable.

Thanks for all the future help.

```
txt_list = []

with open("X:\- Photogrammetry\Python to Correct DXF Colors\InvolvedPontiac.dxf", "r") as in_file, open("X:\- Photogrammetry\Python to Correct DXF Colors\InvolvedPontiacfixed.txt", "w+") as new_file:
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        txt_list.append(line)
Entity = 0
i = 0
while i < len(txt_list):
    if txt_list[i] == "ENTITIES":
        Entity = 1
    if txt_list[i] == " 62" and Entity == 1:
        txt_list[i+1] = " 256"
    i += 1


Layer = 0
j = 0
while j < len(txt_list):
    if txt_list[j] == "LAYER" and txt_list[j+2] != " 7":
        Userinput = input("What color would you like for the layer " +txt_list[j+2] + "? Type 0 for black, 1 for red, 3 for green, 4 for light blue, 5 for blue, 6 for magenta, 7 for white, 8 for dark grey, 9 for medium gray, or 30 for orange.")
        txt_list[j+6] = " " + Userinput

        print ("The " + txt_list[j+2] + " layer now has a color code of " + Userinput)
    j += 1
for item in txt_list:
    new_file.write(item)
print ('\n'.join(txt_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's going on in your code.

But to write a variable to a file, you can use

```
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as new_file:
    new_file.write(variable)
```

Note that the `'w+'` will create the file if it doesn't exist, and will overwrite it if it does.

And if it's all the items in `txt_list` you want to write to that file, 
I don't think I'd `join` them first. Just use a `for` loop:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as new_file:
    for item in txt_list:
        new_file.write(item)
```

This would print every item in that list on a new line in the file.

```
txt_list = []

with open("X:\- Photogrammetry\Python to Correct DXF Colors\InvolvedPontiac.dxf", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        txt_list.append(line)
Entity = 0
i = 0
while i < len(txt_list):
    if txt_list[i] == "ENTITIES":
        Entity = 1
    if txt_list[i] == " 62" and Entity == 1:
        txt_list[i+1] = " 256"
    i += 1


Layer = 0
j = 0
while j < len(txt_list):
    if txt_list[j] == "LAYER" and txt_list[j+2] != " 7":
        Userinput = input("What color would you like for the layer " +txt_list[j+2] + "? Type 0 for black, 1 for red, 3 for green, 4 for light blue, 5 for blue, 6 for magenta, 7 for white, 8 for dark grey, 9 for medium gray, or 30 for orange.")
        txt_list[j+6] = " " + Userinput

        print ("The " + txt_list[j+2] + " layer now has a color code of " + Userinput)
    j += 1

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as new_file:
    for item in txt_list:
        new_file.write(item)

print ('\n'.join(txt_list)
```

Comment: Sorry about the crazy code, it is doing stuff with the text file that is opened. I added your statement at the end but got this error   out_file.write(item)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: That error says you tried to write using the variable name of your first file. I think that might be on me, as I used a similar variable name. Let me edit.

Comment: Even with that, I still get the same error. Could it have to do with my indentation? Is the file closing before I write to it?

Comment: You're not opening the new file first. :D Edited again.

Comment: Sorry I'm so useless, but isn't it being opened at the top of my code, where I also open the in_file?

Comment: No, you don't want to overwrite the file you're reading from. You want to create a new file, with the output in it, right?

Comment: Correct, but aren't I opening up two files at the top? One as a read file (in_file)  and the other as a write (new_file)?

Comment: Yes, but you aren't doing everything inside of that `with`, and you only use your `in_file` to get the `txt_list`, and you only use the `new_file` to write the modified `txt_list` to. So it wouldn't really make sense to do everything in the first `with`. So just do two `with`s , like so.

Comment: My code is apparently opening a new file, as when I go to my directory there is a blank file with my desired name, but this file is empty. So I think the problem is somewhere with the write part.

Comment: You're original code opens both files with the first `with` statement, but then it closes them right after your first `for` loop. Specifically, after its appended all the lines to `txt_list`.

Comment: No Problem, as a side note, if you want to something for every item in  a list, like you are with the `while i < len(txt_list):` loop, it's better just to use a `for` loop.